# Maven - Tomcat 7 - Hibernate MySQL: Broken Pipe Exception when doing mvn deploy

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

For my school exam of programming we need to be able build and deploy a Spring MVC project using maven on a Tomcat (7) server. Most of this stuff is working. `mvn clean install` gives BUILD SUCCESS which is good and I can set up my tomcat server. But whener I try to run or deploy my project with for example `mvn tomcat7:deploy` I get a broken pipe exception, it looks like this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project SpringMVCBlog: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Broken pipe -> [Help 1]
```

The full stack trace (`mvn tomcat7:deploy -e`) is as follows:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project SpringMVCBlog: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Protocol wrong type for socket -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project SpringMVCBlog: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Protocol wrong type for socket
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(TomcatManager.java:880)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:742)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
    ... 22 more
```

I have been struggling with this for way to long and I can't ever seem to find a solution. When I run this project in my IDE (IntelliJ) using a glassfish server it works, but the goal is to run it using the Terminal (I'm on Mac) and deploying it on a Tomcat server.

I've searched but there's not much info about broken pipe exception. I've found that it has something to do with Hibernate and MySQL. I have a basic Hibernate structure in the app, just a basic hibernate.cfg/xml with a few settings and a Util class to get a session so I can save and update on the Database. Broken Pipe would have something to do with Connection Pooling which I am not using (as far as I know) in my project.

I really hope anyone can help me, this problem is extremely frustrating. Please do tell me if any additional code is needed!

**EDIT**

Contents of build section of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
      <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                      <server>TomcatServer</server>
                      <username>root</username>
                      <password>root</password>
                      <path>/SpringMVCBlog</path>
                      <update>true</update>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
    <finalName>SpringMVCBlog</finalName>
  </build>
```

Comment: can you please update mojo plugin info from pom.xml

Comment: @kamoor updated question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @kamoor or do you also need pom.xml dependencies?

Comment: @kamoor How would I go about checking them? I'm suspecting some port Tomcat uses is in use, could that be it?

Comment: @kamoor If I try that I get `INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]` and it doesn't do anything after that

Comment: @kamoor Do you know how I could run it on another port (for example 8090)?

Comment: @kamoor I have, will try and switch both modules of the project to 1.8, I'll report back! Just tried on port 8090 but still broken pipe so it's not that.

Comment: @kamoor My project was on 1.8, tried 1.7 and still Broken Pipe. This is extremely frustrating D:

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. <strike>The only workaround I know until now is to switch back to the old and unsupported org.codehaus.tomcat maven plugin:</strike>

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/tomcat-maven-plugin

Obviously this cannot be the final solution, although I am only able to deploy my war like this at the moment.

Turns out, this error occurs if the web context already exists. Unfortunately the error message does not bother to tell us.

I fixed it by using the official apache tomcat maven plugin ([link](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html)) and the maven redeploy option which is avaiable since tomcat maven plugin >=2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

> *mvn tomcat7:**re**deploy*

if your application is already deployed.

Otherwise you need to undeploy the application first, before doing *mvn tomcat7:deploy*